# How to compress and decompress a file using lzop in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know to compress and decompress a file using `lzop` in command line scripts using following syntax:

```
lzop [-dxlthIVL19] [-qvcfFnNPkUp] [-o file] [-S suffix] [file..]
```

but I would like to see compress and decompress a file in a Python script.
I don't want to use as

```
os.system("lzop [-dxlthIVL19] [-qvcfFnNPkUp] [-o file] [-S suffix] [file..]")
```

in python script.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that is the python package that you are looking for ?

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-lzo/1.08